# How do I fill this tire? The valve stem is inaccessible

Tags: air

This is a 12'' tubeless tire from a go-kart. It's pretty rugged. The valve stem is in a very tight area (see picture). I can barely fit in my finger. There three some bolts with nylock nuts on them that look like if they came out I could split apart the rim. But it's a tubeless tire, so I don't see how that would help.

Anyone know how to deal with this?

[image: Wheel with obstructed valve]

Answer (score 2):

If in fact this is a split rim, you're correct that splitting it will release the bead; if there's even a few pounds of pressure left in the tire, it could also be dangerous (picture getting that rim in the face if one bolt fails after you have the other two nuts off).

Split rims are still seen occasionally on truck tires (older ones), made to ease installing the bead on the rim.  What you have there, however, looks like a two-sided steel spoke rim.  The three lugs hold the wheel to the axle spider or brake drum, and removing those bolts *should* just drop the wheel off the kart.

The solution to your stem accessibility problem is most likely to take the wheel off the kart, take it anywhere that installed tires, and ask them to replace the stem with a bent extended stem, which will protrude from the wheel and give you easier access.  You'll probably have to pay a mount/dismount charge, as well as purchase the new stem(s), but then you'll have easy access to keep your tires correctly filled.

Comment: Seems a bit much to replace a valve that was fine for filling the tyre up at least once before.  Certainly an option but not required.  The short valves are intended to not stick out and so are protected from damage.

Comment: No argument, but the questioner was asking how to make it more accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look for an [inflation chuck](http://www.discoveryparts.com/tire-pressure-gauge-accessories-and-filler-chucks-/760-longacre-restricted-flow-air-filler-chuck-lon-50491.html) for karting use.  It seems you are not the only one with crowded valves.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like those 3 bolts are your salvation. Removing the outer panel of the rim should give you plenty of space to get something on the stem.

Comment: But won't that remove the very bead that the tire is pressing up against? I suppose I should just try and see. But when I see nylocks, I usually assume they are supposed to stay there...

Comment: ...well, nylocks are supposed to stay there until you want them off - they're anti-slip, not anti-removal. [not that I know anything about those rims, btw]